# Google Drive API REST insert permission returning 500 error on node

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

I am currently creating an app that will insert permission to a folder. This folder is shared to a service account.

The user of my app login using oAuth2. Once logged in, my app will insert permission to the folder. The problem is, I am getting 500 internal error.

[image]

Comment: is that your application it looks a lot like postman.

Comment: I used postman here to test my request

Comment: [off topic] May i ask how you got postman to hook up to a Google service account authentication?  Just curious which authentication option you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) Creates a permission for a file or Team Drive.

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions

with a post body of a [Permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource)

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "id": string,
  "type": string,
  "emailAddress": string,
  "domain": string,
  "role": string,
  "allowFileDiscovery": boolean,
  "displayName": string,
  "photoLink": string,
  "expirationTime": datetime,
  "teamDrivePermissionDetails": [
    {
      "teamDrivePermissionType": string,
      "role": string,
      "inheritedFrom": string,
      "inherited": boolean
    }
  ],
  "deleted": boolean
}
```

You are not sending a full permissions resource.

Comment: Can you give sample post body?

Comment: I gave you both the link to the permissions resource and the json resource object.   What more do you need?   You could just do a permissions.get on the file first grabbing the service accounts permissions then edit the emailAddress and the roll in the response and post that back as a create.